# Flask App in Heroku return Only 404 error

Tags: flask

I'm attempting to build a very simple Flask application using just Flask and Python. The application runs perfectly fine on my local machine and I can navigate without errors, but when I deploy to Heroku, I receive a 404 Not Found error for any page that I try to visit, including the index.

manage.py is the root of my app. Here's what it currently looks like:

```
app = create_app(config.DefaultConfig)

if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run()
```

Here's my _ init _.py:
    from flask import Flask
    from .config import DefaultConfig
    from .shopify_bp import shopify_bp
    from .extensions import db
    **all** = ['create_app']

```
DEFAULT_BLUEPRINTS = (
    shopify_bp,
)
def create_app(config=None, blueprints=None,third=None):
    """Create Flask app.

    """
    if blueprints is None:
        blueprints = DEFAULT_BLUEPRINTS
    app = Flask(__name__)
    configure_app(app, config)
    configure_blueprints(app, blueprints)
    return app
```

Here's my Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT manage:app
```

I think everything is set up properly because I'm able to run the app locally without any issues. When I deploy to Heroku, I can see that the site is Up, not Crashed, and I'm not receiving any server errors, just Not Found errors. It's almost as if my routes aren't working or something like that.
Here's what I see in my Heroku logs when I try to access my site's homepage:

```
2018-10-24T09:53:26.797881+00:00 app[web.1]:   ' "{rv}.localdomain", and use that instead.'.format(rv=rv)
2018-10-24T09:53:26.798802+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.37.240.166 - - [24/Oct/2018:09:53:26 +0000] "GET /shopify HTTP/1.1" 404 233 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/37.0.2062.120 Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: Yes! I did. server start to listen ,while I requested it return 404 error as status

Comment: Can you put the code of you flaskr router in your question?

Comment: Please add the real question...

Comment: Sorry ! I'hv updated @Cheshire Cat

Answer (score 0):

You should use the env variable for the host too, here is my Procfile for a Flask application in heroku that is working ok

```
web: gunicorn app:app -b "$HOST:$PORT" -w 3
```

My initial script is called `app` and the flask application inside is created under `app` too, but pay attention to `$HOST` in the bindings